# How to add aditional object property in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to dynamically add additional property in the existing object.
This is what I have:

```
let items = [
   {name: 'Carlsberg', category: 'Beer', price: '4.99'},
   {name: 'Smirnoff', category: 'Vodka', price: '28.99'},
   {name: 'Miller Lite', category: 'Beer', price: '7.99'}
]
```

These are the object properties which I wish to add:

```
categories:{
     beerCounter:2,
     vodkaCounter:1,
}
```

And what I want is to dynamically add additional properties of an object to look like this:

```
items = [
       {name: 'Carlsberg', category: 'Beer', price: '4.99', counter: categories.beerCounter},
       {name: 'Smirnoff', category: 'Vodka', price: '28.99', counter: categories.vodkaCounter},
       {name: 'Miller Lite', category: 'Beer', price: '7.99', counter: categories.beerCounter}
    ]
```

Comment: try Array.map..

Comment: A loop? That's the tried and true method

Comment: @ChrisLi I think he wants to mutate in place not create a new array

Comment: @JaromandaX `Array.map` can modify the original object..

Comment: Try this single line answer : *items.forEach(obj => obj.counter = categories[`${obj.category.toLowerCase()}Counter`])*

Comment: @mhodges ... a sledgehammer can hammer in a thumb tack too. Why use .map ... heard of .forEach?

Comment: @JaromandaX Because using `.forEach` to modify data is impure and breaks functional programming paradigms.

Comment: @mhodges .. the question clearly shows that mutation is desired. No mention of the exalted fuctional programming paradigm in the question.

Comment: @JaromandaX So then mutate properly with a loop, not a functional approach. Speaking of sludgehammers to a thumb tack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Array.forEach`:

```
let items = [
   {name: 'Carlsberg', category: 'Beer', price: '4.99'},
   {name: 'Smirnoff', category: 'Vodka', price: '28.99'},
   {name: 'Miller Lite', category: 'Beer', price: '7.99'}
];

const categories = {
     beerCounter: 2,
     vodkaCounter: 1,
};

items.forEach(item => {
  item.counter = item.category === 'Beer' ? categories.beerCounter : categories.vodkaCounter;
})

console.table(items);
```

Comment: Just wanted this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate your array using `forEach`, setting the `counter` property using the lower-cased `category` value for each item:

```js
let items = [{
    name: 'Carlsberg', category: 'Beer', price: '4.99'
  },
  {
    name: 'Smirnoff', category: 'Vodka', price: '28.99'
  },
  {
    name: 'Miller Lite', category: 'Beer', price: '7.99'
  }
]

let categories = {
  beerCounter: 2,
  vodkaCounter: 1,
}

items.forEach(i => i.counter = categories[`${i.category.toLowerCase()}Counter`])

console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the **Array.forEach()** method.

I advise you to do this with a regex, it avoids keyboard errors if your category ever comes in all lowercase or all uppercase, or even a mixture of the two, sometimes our fingers wander from typing code haha

```js
let items = [
    {name: 'Carlsberg', category: 'Beer', price: '4.99'},
    {name: 'Smirnoff', category: 'Vodka', price: '28.99'},
    {name: 'Miller Lite', category: 'Beer', price: '7.99'}
 ]

const categories = {
    beerCounter: 2,
    vodkaCounter: 1,
};

items.forEach(item => {
    if (/^beer/i.test(item.category)) {
        item.counter = categories.beerCounter;
    }
    if (/^vodka/i.test(item?.category)) {
        item.counter = categories.vodkaCounter;
    }
});

console.log(items);
```

Good luck dude !

Answer (score 1):

```
let items = [
   {name: 'Carlsberg', category: 'Beer', price: '4.99'},
   {name: 'Smirnoff', category: 'Vodka', price: '28.99'},
   {name: 'Miller Lite', category: 'Beer', price: '7.99'}
]

items.forEach((item) => {
  if(item.category === 'Beer'){
  item.categories = categories.beerCounter
}
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` or `forEach`

```
let items = [
   {name: 'Carlsberg', category: 'Beer', price: '4.99'},
   {name: 'Smirnoff', category: 'Vodka', price: '28.99'},
   {name: 'Miller Lite', category: 'Beer', price: '7.99'}
]

const categories = {
    beerCounter:2,
    vodkaCounter:1,
}

items.forEach(item=>{
  if(item.category === 'Beer')
    item.counter = categories.beerCounter;
  if(item.category === 'Vodka')
    item.counter = categories.vodkaCounter;
})

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Why use .map of you throw away the array of undefineds you created for no reason at all?

Comment: It is preferable to use `forEach`, more than `map` if you we're not going to use the retourned values.